# Why I can't install brew on macOS?

Tags: macos, environment-variables, homebrew

I am trying to install `brew` on my co-worker's macOS. I have brew on my computer.
Not sure why we are having problems to install it on his computer. I am following this [turial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-homebrew-on-macos).

When I run:

```
% brew doctor
zsh: command not found: brew
```

It says `brew` was not installed.

I already edited his path at `.zshrc`. However, I did not put the comment suggested on the tutorial. Not sure if it makes any difference:

```
@Michaels-MacBook-Air ~ % cat .zshrc
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

This is on:

```
@Michaels-MacBook-Air ~ % pwd
/Users/michaels
```

In addition, I already executed:

```
/bin/bash install.sh
```

Which return the following warning:

```
Warning: /opt/homebrew/bin is not in your PATH.
 Instructions on how to configure your shell for Homebrew
 can be found in the 'Next steps' section below.
```

And I checked xcode-select is installed:

```
@Michaels-MacBook-Air ~ % xcode-select --version
xcode-select version 2396.
```

I am suspicious his PATH might be wrong:

```
@Michaels-MacBook-Air ~ % echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/System/Cryptexes/App/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Applications/Keybase.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin
```

Is this problematic?
If no, what else could be causing a problem?

Comment: Forget about shady tutorials. Use the [official documentation](https://brew.sh) on https://brew.sh and follow the steps as described there.

Comment: Apparently you didn't notice this message when you ran the installation script: "Warning: /opt/homebrew/bin is not in your PATH." I'm guessing your coworker has an Apple Silicon (i.e., M1 chip) based system and you're using an older x86_64 based system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [Homebrew documentation](https://docs.brew.sh/Installation):

> This script installs Homebrew to its default, supported, best prefix (/usr/local for macOS Intel, /opt/homebrew for Apple Silicon and /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew for Linux)

If your coworker has an M1 or M2 mac, you'll need to add /opt/homebrew/bin to PATH.

Answer (score 3):

To install brew, just run the following script:

/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"

Homebrew Official Documentation:
https://brew.sh/